Does "__attribute__(used)" apply to every function that is declared after it used?
I was going through the startup code for startup_stm32f4xx and I see that __attribute__ ((used)) is used before the declaring the functions. So is the attribute applied only to Reset_Handler or to all the functions?
Full code, and relevant extract:
__attribute__ ((used))
void WEAK  Reset_Handler(void);
void WEAK  NMI_Handler(void);
void WEAK  HardFault_Handler(void);
void WEAK  MemManage_Handler(void);
void WEAK  BusFault_Handler(void);
void WEAK  UsageFault_Handler(void);
void WEAK  SVC_Handler(void);
void WEAK  DebugMon_Handler(void);
void WEAK  PendSV_Handler(void);
void WEAK  SysTick_Handler(void);

I could not find any resource explaining how it works in the scenario shown above

Just Reset_Handler.

The line break after the attribute is meaningless. There's no difference between the following two snippets:
__attribute__ ((used))
void WEAK  Reset_Handler(void);

__attribute__ ((used)) void WEAK  Reset_Handler(void);

Furthermore, the following two snippets are completely separate declarations:
__attribute__ ((used)) void WEAK  Reset_Handler(void);

void WEAK  NMI_Handler(void);

__attribute__ ((used)) attaches to the function, just like void defines its return value.
Docs:

This attribute, attached to a function, means that code must be emitted for the function even if it appears that the function is not referenced. This is useful, for example, when the function is referenced only in inline assembly.


It probably wasn't the intent of the author to only mark Reset_Handler as used.
Functions are extern by default, so all these functions are extern. extern functions can't be optimized away. The used attribute prevents a function from being optimized away, so the used attribute is entirely redundant on extern functions.
This would explain why it has gone unnoticed that the attribute was mistakenly only applied to the first function instead of all of them.
